# A question in proof of a theorem in Galois Theory from Hungerford Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, automorphism-group

I am self studying Fields and Galois Theory from Algebra by Thomas Hungerford and I have a question in this theorem s proof.

Its image[image]

> I have question in line 1 where author writes "In any case $G$ is  a subgroup of $\operatorname{Aut}_K F $ .
>
> Definition of $\operatorname{Aut}_K F $ is group of all $K$-automorphisms of FF , where $G$ is a group of automorphisms of $F$.

So, I think since conditions are on $\operatorname{Aut}_K F $ that it must be a $K$-module homomorphism , so $G$ must be a larger set $\operatorname{Aut}_K F$ , but the opposite is given. So, can anyone please explain why opposite is given.

Comment: No, $G$ need not be "larger" because it is assumed that $K$ is the fixed field of $G$ in $F$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition $\operatorname{Aut}_KF$ is the group of all automorphisms of $F$ that fix $K$ pointwise. So if $G$ is a group of automorphisms of $F$ that fix $K$ pointwise, then $G$ is a subgroup of $\operatorname{Aut}_KF$.

Comment: sorry I should have paid more attention.